# Amcharts 4: How to combine tooltips of LineSeries

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a chart containing 3 LineSeries. Sometimes, the lines cross each other. At these points only the single tooltip of the last added series is displayed.

[image]

How can I combine those tooltips into one single single tooltip that contains the information on all three series, in case the points are at the same position?

I build the chart using LineSeries and place CircleBullets on them:

```
/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "cars";
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series1.name = "Cars";
series1.strokeWidth = 3;
series1.tensionX = 0.7;
bullet1 = series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet1.tooltipText = `[bold]YEAR {categoryX}[/]
----
cars: {cars}`;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueY = "motorcycles";
series2.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series2.name = "Motorcycles";
series2.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.tensionX = 0.7;
bullet2 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet2.tooltipText = `[bold]YEAR {categoryX}[/]
----
motorcycles: {motorcycles}`;

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueY = "bicycles";
series3.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
series3.name = "Bicycles";
series3.strokeWidth = 3;
series3.tensionX = 0.7;
bullet3 = series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet3.tooltipText = `[bold]YEAR {categoryX}[/]
----
Bicycles: {bicycles}`;
```

full example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ommRPp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like Albondi was saying, what you can start with is the chart cursor so we can have all the tooltips trigger all the time:

```js
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

From there, if you want to filter which tooltips get shown and what gets shown in the remaining tooltip, I suggest setting an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) on each bullet's `tooltipText`. What triggers a tooltip to begin with is if the object has a non-empty `tooltipText` property. So for the tooltips we want to hide, with an adapter we can just return `""` to hide them at will.

To determine if we're hovering over multiple bullets, in this case we can just check if they have the same exact value, we know the value keys are `cars`, `motorcycles`, and `bicycles`, so if they're exactly the same on hover, suppress two of the tooltips, and modify the text of the other to show data for all three. The second parameter of the adapter will be the object we're hovering over, its `dataItem.dataContext` will have references to the data/values we're looking to compare.

```js
bullet1.adapter.add("tooltipText", blankTooltipTextOnSameValues);
bullet2.adapter.add("tooltipText", blankTooltipTextOnSameValues);
bullet3.adapter.add("tooltipText", function(text, target) {
  var data = target.dataItem.dataContext;
  if (data.bicycles === data.motorcycles && data.bicycles === data.cars) {
    return `[bold]YEAR {categoryX}[/]
----
Cars: {cars}
Motorcycles: {motorcycles}
Bicycles: {bicycles}`;
  }
  return text;
});

function blankTooltipTextOnSameValues(text, target) {
  var data = target.dataItem.dataContext;
  if (data.bicycles === data.motorcycles && data.bicycles === data.cars) {
    return "";
  }
  return text;
}
```

Here's a fork of your code sample with the above changes:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a9c1d3eff9170c04f18e134bd6940daa

You can omit the Chart Cursor if you want, then you'd have to hover over the bullets individually for the tooltip to show. Since `series3` is the latest addition to the chart, it will have a higher stacking order and will cover the other bullets at the same point, so the adapter above will achieve the same effect with/without the Chart Cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Combine a cursor with tooltip positioning. You can create a cursor this way:

```
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

That will show all the labels but with poor positioning.

You should use a `tooltip` object to position the tooltip of each of the series:

```
var t = new am4core.Tooltip();
t.dy=-20; // This will move the tooltip 20 pixels up
bullet2.tooltipText = `[bold]YEAR {categoryX}[/]
---- 
motorcycles: {motorcycles}`
bullet2.tooltip = t;
```

Have a look of all the different positioning options [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tooltip/).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your code and it looks like the cursor displays all tooltips at the same time no matter if the series overlap. Is there a way to only show all tooltips if the mouse pointer hovers over bullets that are at the same position?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to do that. Maybe try searching the docs about [Cursor](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xycursor/) or [LineSeries](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/lineseries/).

Comment: @Hokascha I think you will need to make custom onHover functions to achieve what you want to do.