# Amcharts, is it possible to set series tooltip when use ValueAxis for x-axis

Tags: amcharts

this is my first post so please excuse me if I missed anything.

I'm trying to build an elevation profile chart in amcharets using its XY chart. The data will look like below, where distance will be the X value, and two elevations will be the Y value as two line series.

```
[
{distance: 1.0, elevation1: 10.1, elevation2: 5.2},
{distance: 1.3, elevation1: 10.5, elevation2: 5.1},
{distance: 1.4, elevation1: 10.2, elevation2: 5.5},
{distance: 2.0, elevation1: 10.3, elevation2: 5.6},
{distance: 2.6, elevation1: 10.5, elevation2: 5.7},
{distance: 2.7, elevation1: 10.9, elevation2: 5.9},
{distance: 3.3, elevation1: 11.1, elevation2: 5.8},
…
]
```

In amcharts when using Date Axis or Category Axis as X-axis, it will show tooltips of all series when moving the cursor over the chart, if the series has a Y value for a given X value. However I couldn’t use either because in my case my X values are not equally distributed but have this linear relationship.  E.g. the if the x value (distance) = 1.3, it should sit at 3/10 between the 1 and 2 marker. But if I use ValueAxis as the X-axis, the chart won't show the series tooltip at all. So my question is, whether there's a way to allow the chart to show series tooltip even if the x-axis is ValueAxis, or if there’s a way in amcharts allow me to build such type of chart with tooltip turned on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When both x and y axes are Value axes, you can make the cursor to snap to the nearest data point by setting:

```
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series
```

Like in this demo: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/zoomable-bubble-chart/

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeroin. It solved my initial question. In fact I have multiple line seires and I hope there's a way to show the tooltip for all series for a given X value. The snapToSeries seems can't do that. I have updated my original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question
It use bullets
[Amcharts 4: How to combine tooltips of LineSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766570/amcharts-4-how-to-combine-tooltips-of-lineseries)

I change example, where bullets is invisible, make radius to 0

```
bullet1.circle.radius = 0;
```

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a9c1d3eff9170c04f18e134bd6940daa?editors=0010